# Kafka Rotating Garbage Collection Logs

Tags: rotation, apache-kafka

I have Kafka,

included logging Garbage Collection logs

/opt/kafka/logs/kafkaServer-gc.log

All logs working Rotating, except Garbage Collection logs.

for example option in /opt/kafka/config/log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n
```

How make option for Rotating Garbage Collection Logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC logs are not configured by log4j but instead by JVM arguments.

Since Kafka 0.11, by default, Kafka should keep up to 10 files of 100MB. See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L244-L257

If you want a different settings, you can export `KAFKA_GC_LOG_OPTS` with the desired configuration.